# Running Error caused by cv::resize() when transitioning opencv from 2.4.13 to 3.3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

The below code is a sample.

```
cv::Mat mat  = cv::Mat ( 500, 400, CV_32F, cv::Scalar::all ( 2.0 ) );
cv::Mat mat2;
cv::resize(mat, mat2, cv::Size(400,600), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

This give me this error

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unknown/unsupported array type) in getMat_, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1319
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1319: error: (-213) Unknown/unsupported array type in function getMat_
```

I have installed opencv 2.4.13 in /usr/locl as the default version and opencv 3.3.1 along with the ROS kinetic.

My cmake project A was built upon opencv 2.4.13 and it works properly. Now I need to transition to opencv 3.3.1 because another catkin package B depends on A and opencv 3.3.1. However, the problem occurs as above and I cannot fix it after day's googling.

Note that cv::resize works normally when tested using a single cpp file based project depending on either opencv 2.4.13 or 3.3.1.
It also works normally in project A depending upon opencv 2.4.13.

However, it causes running error in project A depending upon opencv 3.3.1

Any ideas are welcomed

I have also tried to compile both A and B using Opencv 2 and then I use  find_package( OpenCV 2 REQUIRED) in my cmakelists.txt file. Another ruuning error caused by resize() was reported as below (may vary):

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented 
Unknown/unsupported array type) in getMat_, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1319 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1319: 
error: (-213) Unknown/unsupported array type in function getMat_
```

or

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (You should explicitly call mapHost/unmapHost methods for ogl::Buffer object) in getMat_, 
file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1299
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1299: 
error: (-213) You should explicitly call mapHost/unmapHost methods for ogl::Buffer object in function getMat_
```

crazy( ⊙ o ⊙ )！

Comment: Did you visit and try the method which is mentioned here(https://answers.ros.org/question/212860/at-an-impasse-using-opencv/)

Comment: Yeah, I use  find_package( OpenCV 2 REQUIRED) in my cmakelists.txt file. I'm wondering why the error was repored about ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I re-implement those related functions where cv::resize is used in project A in my current project B, then it works.(⊙o⊙)